# Ignoring a word among a pattern in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a pattern which doesn't contain another word.
I mean I'm trying to match something beginning by `a`  and finishing by  `b` while ignoring matches which contain `oui`.

Here's the String I'm working on:

```js
a oui b
a uoi b
a zzz b
b zzz a
```

So far, I found this:

```regex
/a (.[^oui]*?) b/gs
```

The problem is that he's ignoring every matches which contains a word with a `o` or `u` or `i` so including the match containing `uoi`. Is there a way ignoring only the `oui` word among my pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/^a(?:[^o]|o(?!ui))+b$/
```

That's an 'a' at the start, followed by (one or more of) either "not an o" or "an o not followed by ui", and then a 'b' at the end.

Comment: Perfect! I just needed it lazy so I added a `?` after the `+`.

Answer (score 1):

Use negative lookaround: /a ((?!oui).)* b/.

Answer (score 0):

```
/a (?!oui).*? b/
```

It's simple and clean.

Comment: This will match a .*oui b, it just avoids a oui.* b. /a ((?!oui).)* b/ will avoid this.

Comment: To Kugland: Did you test them all?

Comment: To Kugland: /a ((?!oui).)* b/.test('a oui b')  is false, so /a ((?!oui).)* b/.test('a ooui b') is.